# Angular list of Items not updates when it changes in Service

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, observable, subject

I have two components: one parent which contain form to add a file, and other child which show a list of items (files) added. I want to update my table of items after adding one, I subscribed but **don't** detect changes when its appended (sorry for my bad English), here is my code:

'this.dataSource = resp.files;' isn't updated again, just once the first time.

### SOLVED!

files.component.ts

```js
    export class FilesComponent implements OnInit {
      dataSource;
      columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'year', 'created_at', '_id'];
      expandedElement: File | null;
      constructor(
        public _file: FileService
      ) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this._file.$files.subscribe((resp: any) => {
          this._file.getFiles();  //*******PARTIALLY SOLVED i call getFiles() inside but
                                  // Now constantly call getFiles()  :/
          this.dataSource = resp.files;
        });
      }
    }
```

add-file.component.ts

```js
    send() {
    const newFile = {
      name: this.name,
      status: 'activo',
      year: this.yearCtrl.value,
      from_id: this.selectedFrom._id,
      career_id: this.selectedCareer
    };
    this._file.newFile(newFile).subscribe( (resp: any) => {
      // this._file.getFiles();  //*******Removed
      console.log(resp);
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    };
```

Service.ts

```js
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FileService {
      private headers;
      public URL = URL;
      private files = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
      public $files = this.files.asObservable();

      constructor(
        private _http: HttpClient
      ) {
        this.headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        // this.getFiles();  //*******Removed
      }

      getFiles(id: String = null) {
         this._http.get(URL + '/file', { headers: this.headers }).subscribe( (resp: any) => {
          return this.files.next(resp);
        });
      }

      newFile( newFile: any) {
        console.log(newFile);
        return this._http.post(this.URL + '/file', newFile, { headers: this.headers }).subscribe( (resp: any) => {
          this.getFiles(); 
        });
      }
    }
```

I'm using angular material table but my component.ts doesn't read the changes in the service var.

Comment: you don't call any getFiles or newFile method so $files is never updated !

Comment: sry in my second component i do, now i will update

Comment: Do you need the Subject/Observable in the service? I would first try to get this app working by directly returning the result of `get()` and `post()` from the service.

Comment: i have 2 separates components, one with form to add and other to show table of files, i want update the table when i add an item

Comment: You have set the initial value of behavior subject as [ ] , and in the ngOnInit you are trying access files ( resp.files ) from the value emitted by $files observable. Make sure you are passing the intended value to behavior subject, in the service's getfiles method, array or object containing files array.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem calling **child** method getFile() from **parent** when file is created, using Subject to get notified each time i send a new File.

> Parent component.ts

```js
send() {
    const newFile = {
      name: this.name,
      status: 'activo',
      year: this.yearCtrl.value,
      from_id: this.selectedFrom._id,
      career_id: this.selectedCareer
    };
    this._file.newFile(newFile).subscribe( (resp: any) => {
      this.reloadFiles.next(true);
    });
  };
```

> Parent HTML

```html
    <app-files [reload]="reloadFiles" [file]="searchFilter"></app-files>
```

> Child component.ts

```js
@Input() reload: Subject<boolean>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getFiles();
    this.reload.subscribe(v => {
      this.getFiles();
    });
  } 

getFiles() {
    this._file.getFiles().subscribe( (resp: any ) => {
       this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(resp.files);
    });
}
```

> Service.ts

```js
getFiles(id: String = null) {
    return this._http.get(URL + '/file', { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

I dont know if is the correct way but is working fine!
Thx